# open("/tmp", O_RDWR | O_TMPFILE, 0) fails with Permission denied

Tags: c

I'm trying to open a tempfile using

```
fd = open("/tmp", O_RDWR | O_TMPFILE, 0);
if (fd == -1) {
    perror("open()");
    exit(1);
}
```

and I am getting "open(): Permission denied".

I have permissions in /tmp:

```
drwxrwxrwt  13 root root 1.2K Apr 23 13:55 /tmp/
```

and I believe my kernel is new enough for O_TMPFILE:

```
Linux frosties 3.14-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.14.2-1 (2014-04-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What am I missing?

Comment: O_TMPFILE takes a directory path. The create file has no name. Using "/tmp/tmpfile.txt" results in "No such file or directory" since that doesn't exist.

Comment: not all file systems support O_TMPFILE flag. Which one you have mounted under /tmp ?

Comment: @naltipar Please do read the ls output in the question.

Comment: Everyone commenting or answering: please refer to the man page for [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).

Comment: you should specify `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR` at least as mode instead of `0`, otherwise you don't have read and write permissions to the file.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe open fails because the mode argument woudn't allow for the requestion operations (O_RDWR).

Comment: `/tmp` is usually a directory, so `open( "/tmp", ...)` can also fail with errno set to EISDIR for a number of reasons.  Some OS's don't support `open()` calls on a directory, some do but only with the proper flags set.

Comment: "Fun" fact: Unlike every other syscall, `open` does not fail if passed invalid flags, it just silently ignores them and does the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call failed because you have specified mode `0`, which means no permissions.  See [this LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/619146/) for a discussion of this behavior of the Linux kernel, and an apparent bugfix.

Comment: "In the case of open() on x86-64 machines, things work out of sheer luck: the mode argument just happens to be sitting in the right register when glibc makes the call into the kernel." - sigh.